# create user defined id and new data at time of reindex elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, reindex

I am going to reindex with below query like.

```
{
  "source": {
    "index": "demodata"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_twitter",
    "op_type": "create"
  },
   "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source['project'] = 'Personal3'",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

When project change same data/index need to reindex with new project name. But I am getting Conflict. I hope if there is any options to update the Id I can solve this issue.

Comment: Hi, Don't you want to overwrite the older data? Do you want to create new document with new id?

Comment: I am want to create new data every time when reindex happen. No need to override.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate new ids in each time you reindex your data you need to do something like this:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "demodata"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_twitter"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source['foo'] = 'Personal3'; ctx._id=null",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

This reindex query make a null id for each document and elasticsearch creates new id for each of them. Please let me know if you have any problem with this.

Comment: Hi, Did it work for you?